# MapThread problem

Tags: list-manipulation, core-language

I would like to do the following:

```
startData = {{3.9, 5.2}, {5.5, 6.7}, {8.8, 5.3}, {3.9, 3.6}, {4.3, 3.8}};
endData = {{3.0, 6}, {5.3, 7}, {8.5, 6}, {4, 3.6}, {4.2, 4}};
MapThread[Arrow, {startData, endData}]
```

The problem is that `Arrow` requires the start and end point be bracketed, e.g.,

```
Arrow[{{3.9, 5.2}, {3., 6}}]
```

How can I add the extra brackets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Arrow[{##}]&` as the function in `MapThread`.  See [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html) for more.

Comment: OK, great this works! I'll have to look into this, not fully sure about the syntax.

Answer (score 3):

You just have to use slightly customized variant of `Arrow`.

```
startData = {{3.9, 5.2}, {5.5, 6.7}, {8.8, 5.3}, {3.9, 3.6}, {4.3, 3.8}}
endData = {{3.0, 6}, {5.3, 7}, {8.5, 6}, {4, 3.6}, {4.2, 4}};
MapThread[Arrow[{#1, #2}] &, {startData, endData}]
```

> ```
> {Arrow[{{3.9, 5.2}, {3., 6}}], Arrow[{{5.5, 6.7}, {5.3, 7}}], 
>  Arrow[{{8.8, 5.3}, {8.5, 6}}], Arrow[{{3.9, 3.6}, {4, 3.6}}], 
>  Arrow[{{4.3, 3.8}, {4.2, 4}}]}
> ```

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for numbering the slots, know I hope I'll remember how to do it.